# Jasper fighting with JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jar, jasper-reports

Hi I am trying to use Jasper (4.0.2) reports with JBoss 6 using an XML file as data source. However, there is a fair amount of over lap of required library JARs and as I can't exclude the JBoss libs I have excluded any conflicting Jasper JARs. When I run the program on its own all is well however when I re-introduce the JBoss libs I get this when trying to execute anything Jasper related:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/Logger$AttachmentKey
    at org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Slf4jLoggerFactory.java:31)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory(StaticLoggerBinder.java:33)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:240)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.<clinit>(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:180)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:205)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:170)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:154)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:111)
    at com.ehive.report.ejb3.RenderReportBean.execute(RenderReportBean.java:56)
    at com.ehive.report.ejb3.RenderReportBean.main(RenderReportBean.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.Logger$AttachmentKey
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 14 more
```

The Log4j library it seems to be complaining about is the same version in both Jboss and Jasper so I am confused by the exception.

Can anyone tell me is this a general compatibility problem or is there a safe way to include all required libraries without the conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was with the inclusion of both the jasperreports-4.0.2.jar and jasperreports-javaflow-4.0.2.jar files. Once the "javaflow" JAR was removed all deployed smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same as you are  using
 `*common-annotations,commons-beanutils-1.7.0,commons-collections-3.2.1,commons-digester-1.8,commons-logging-1.1.1jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.23,jasperreports-3.7.2,slf4j-api-1.5.10,xmlbeans-2.3.0*` and other jar in JSF + spring web app succesfully !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (although not the same) with my Jasper reports. It wouldn't even compile because of class conflicts with weblogic jars. My solution was to compile the jasper jrxml files using a separate ant target which had a separate classpath defined. Once the jrxml was compiled into jasper files, I didn't have any trouble running it within the app server though.

Comment: Weblogic <= 8.1 used to rename the copy of thebundled Xerces so it was no longer org.apache.xerces...

Answer (score 0):

You could repackages the classes that conflict namely log4j and Jasper w/ something like jar jar links(???). This of course will mean you have two copies of log4j albeit with different package names and a custom jasper. However once done things should just work unless there are hardcoded strings in code that refer to the original package names in log4j. Hopefully this wont be a problem :)